# How to retrieve keys from the retrofit call, that is wrapped in generics?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, mvvm, android-room

I have an app, where's an api call, which contains some data (which is stored in `HashMap<String, Double>`), that I'd like to store in `List`, and later on, push values of this list, to the database. Here is some logged response, from my `ViewModel`:

```
Success(data={A=1.1, B=2.2 ... })
```

As you can see, the response is wrapped in generic class. I don't know how I can retrieve keys from this response. I feel like I've tried everything...

**Generic class**

```
sealed class RetrofitResult{
 data class Success<out T>(val myData: T) : RetrofitResult()
 data class Error(val myError: Throwable) : RetrofitResult()
}
```

**Repository**

```
    suspend fun getData(): RetrofitResult{
        return try {
            val response = myApi.makeCall()
            RetrofitResult.Success(myData= response.body()?.myHashMap)
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            RetrofitResult.Error(error = exception.cause!!)
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
private val _dataStatus = MutableLiveData<RetrofitResult>()
val latestRates: LiveData<RetrofitResult> get() = _dataStatus 


    fun myData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val apiResponse = myRepository.getData()
                _dataStatus .value = apiResponse 

            } catch (exception: IOException) {
                //TODO
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I'd like to get keys from the response, and insert the in a `List`, so I would have something like:

```
val dummyList: List<String> = listof("A", "B" ... )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should push the generic type up to the sealed class super type, so that generic type can be in all the parameter and return types.

The Error type can specify that it satisfies `Nothing` which is logically treated as the subtype of all types so you won't have to fool with specifying it when using individual instances of Error.

```
sealed class RetrofitResult<out T>{
  data class Success<out T>(val myData: T) : RetrofitResult<T>()
  data class Error(val myError: Throwable) : RetrofitResult<Nothing>()
}
```

Then you specify this type when working with the sealed class type:

```
suspend fun getData(): RetrofitResult<HashMap<String, Double>>{
  //...
}

//...

private val _dataStatus = MutableLiveData<RetrofitResult<HashMap<String, Double>>>()
```

I specified a non-nullable data type. You need to handle the possible case of the body being null. Maybe turn that into an error.

I also recommend using `Map` for your data type instead of `HashMap`. HashMap is not only mutable, which is error-prone for using in a LiveData or Flow, but also it is an oddly specific subtype of MutableMap for no reason.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it. That saved me another couple of days of pain  while trying to figure it out. Also, is `SortedMap` good? Instead of using an `Map`?

Comment: SortedMap is iffy. It's a MutableMap so it is error prone to use with LiveData and Flows. However, specifying it as a type can communicate to the programmer who's using the data that it's guaranteed to be sorted, since the Map interface on its own does not guarantee this. But then you should put in the documentation of the LiveData property that the returned map must not be mutated, and you must also remember not to reuse the instance you are passing to the LiveData.

Comment: IMO, you might as well use Map and put in the documentation that it is guaranteed to be sorted. You have to clarify using documentation one way or the other, so use the one where the compiler enforces safe use of it. Worst case scenario is if the programmer doesn't notice the documentation, they redundantly sort it which will only cause unnecessary CPU use but not cause bugs.